# Symfony - render twig file in myClass

Tags: php, symfony, utilities

Let's say i have my own class

```
  <?php
  class myClass {
    public function myFunction(){
    $template = $this->render('sometwigfile');
    }
  }
```

What should i do if I want to load twig file to variable NOT IN CONTROLLER?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :

```
$template = $this->renderView('whatever.html.twig')
```

`render()` renders the full HTTP response including the headers, and returns a **Response** object, while `renderView()` just gives you the rendered view (i.e. some HTML, in your case)

Answer (score 0):

You can inject `templating` service to render twig template and store it in a variable.